# Replace Input.GetAxis to touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to code the car's rotation system as I move left and right. I use the following code for this.

```cs
float steer = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

float finalangel = steer * 45f;
wheelcoll[0].steerAngle = finalangel;
```

But I want to set it for the phone. When the user touches the screen of the phone and keeps his hand on the screen of the phone, the car goes to the left and stays. When the user removes his hand from the phone, the car returns to its original position. But when doing this process, I want the car to turn in the right direction.

How can I do this?

I tried this too:

```cs
[SerializeField] Rigidbody rb;
  
public  Vector3 targetpostion;
public int Speed;

public bool FirstLaneBlueCar;
public bool BlueCar;

public Vector2 Xpos;

public float rotatlerptime;
 
bool rottrue;

void Start()
{
    rottrue = false;
    BlueCar = false;
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {     
        BlueCar = true;
        rottrue = true;
        LeftButtonPressed();
    }else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        BlueCar = true;
        rottrue = true;
        LeftButtonPressed();
    }

    if (!rottrue)
    {
        if (transform.position.x <= 4f)
        {
            Debug.Log(">-.5");
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), rotatlerptime * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (transform.position.x >= 3f)
        {
            Debug.Log(">.5f");
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), rotatlerptime * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
       
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(targetpostion, Space.World);

    if (BlueCar)
    {
        if (FirstLaneBlueCar)
        {
            if (rottrue)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, -60f, 0), rotatlerptime * Time.deltaTime);
                Invoke("rot2", .1f);
            }

            Invoke("left", .1f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (rottrue)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 60f, 0), rotatlerptime * Time.deltaTime);
                Invoke("rot2", .1f);
            }

            Invoke("right", .1f);
        }

    }
}

public void rot2()
{
    rottrue = false;
}

void left()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(-Xpos.y, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), .08f);
}

void right()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(-Xpos.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), .08f);
}


public void LeftButtonPressed()
{
    if (FirstLaneBlueCar)
    {
        FirstLaneBlueCar = false;
    }
    else
    {
        FirstLaneBlueCar = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can track the first [touch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html) position, and make the respective calculations in the `Update` method, comparing the previous touch position with the current one.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length < 1)
        return;

    var touch = Input.touches[0];
    var deltaPosition = touch.deltaPosition;

    // Move the car according to the shift in touch position
}
```

You can also save the touch ID when the touch has just begun, so you can track the same touch later (user can have multiple fingers on the screen).

Use [Touch.fingerId](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) for that.

Comment: Sorry did not notice .